# Tool to find xpath and iframe id

Tags: web, automation, firebug

I'm automating a web page which contains several nested iframes. This makes it hard for me to find the proper locator for the elements. I use firebug, the f12 tools ... to get xpath etc. but I miss something here, the iframe id.
Does someone know a tool where I can point on an element on the web page, and get the xpath and the iframe id?

THX

Comment: If you want to get a specific `<iframe>` element, why don't you use `document.getElementById('someiframe')`? Or do you want to reference the elements **within** the iframes?

Comment: The problem is one step before, I need to know in which iframe my e.g. button is located. Therefore I'm looking for a tool which tells me to which iframe a element belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug displays the iframes containing the inspected element within its ancestor path:

[image: Ancestor path within *HTML* panel]

By clicking on the buttons within the ancestor path you can jump to the related iframe.

To get the XPath for an iframe right-click on it within the *HTML* panel and choose *Copy Minimal XPath* or *Copy XPath* from the context menu.